# Can jQuery event namespaces contain dashes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, namespaces

Can jQuery event namespaces contain dashes (hyphens)? I have long namespaces and I want to separate them with dashes, is it possible? I didn't find any documentation on http://api.jquery.com/unbind/. Do you know where it's documented?

The code is something like this:

```
var close_menu_event_element = $('{selector}');
var event = 'click.our-top-menu'; // Can be also 'click.our-compose-menu'
if (close_menu_event_element.length > 0) {
    close_menu_event_element.unbind(event);
    if (typeof(func) === "function") {
        close_menu_event_element.bind(event, func);
    }
}
```

**Update**: bind and unbind work in Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m with namespaces with dashes, but I want to know if it works in any browser with jQuery? We are using jQuery 2.1.1.

Comment: please share some relevant code and explain it.

Comment: I agree with @MillieSmith - suck it and see is the best way to learn. That said, yes they can.

Comment: I want to see it in the documentation before I try it, there might be difference between browsers and versions and I want to know if it will work in all browsers and versions. @MillieSmith

Comment: @Uri The first thing to do would be to see if it works at all. That would be the time to come back and ask whether it's cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if jQuery gets the last word on this, but the answer is **no** according to the jQuery documentation for [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names).

> Namespaces should contain upper/lowercase letters and digits only.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know if it works in any browser with jQuery

Yes, it will work in all major browsers without problems. All jQuery do to resolve namespaces is split selector string by `.` character. Something like this:

```
namespaces = ( tmp[2] || "" ).split( "." ).sort();
```

Nothing fancy here, split method will work everywhere, you can use `-` or `@` if you want in namespace substring.

Here is the best documentation: [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/34da7d552982d8ab7b18c2ceca9786d5023930f6/src/event.js#L86).

Comment: Thank you! By the way, do you know why they used "myEvents" as the namespace in http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ ? Is it possible that jQuery will not support namespaces with dashes in the future?

Comment: Feeling cringes at calling source code the "best" documentation. Only if it's the "only" documentation. See my answer.